# Post thumbnail options in Woocommerce 3.3

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with my website's post thumbnails. The products image are shown as `100x100 px` images (too small).

I would like to find the source code for thumbs from front-page, because I don't like that they are displayed in such small size. The original size of my images is `300x250 px`.

**Where is the location of the code that sets the size of products thumbnails? How can I change the thumbnails size to the original one?**

```
<a class="product_thumbnail_wrap" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php
    /**
    * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
    *
    * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
    * @hooked shophistic_lite_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
    */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, You don't want to change the code itself, but there are some parameters available, where You can change how the images should be displayed. If You would google a little, there is [this page](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/12/11/wc-3-3-image-size-improvements/), where is written following:

> With **WooCommerce 3.3** theme authors can now declare image sizes via the `add_theme_support function`. Declaring image sizes this way will take priority over any other settings and also hide the image settings section in the admin area.

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', array(
'thumbnail_image_width' => 150,
'single_image_width' => 322,
) );
```

---

**Thumbnail Cropping**

> A new thumbnail cropping section in the customizer will allow store owners to select one of three cropping ration settings with visual cues:
>
> - 1:1 (Square scropping)
> - Custom (Store owner can enter a custom aspect ratio)
> - Uncropped (Preserve single image aspect ratio)
>
> Image sizes are then calculated based on the cropping option selected and the image width.
>
> **It is important to note that Single Product Images are uncropped and not affected by the cropping settings.**